# Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I always get the error:

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `characters`;
CREATE TABLE `characters`(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `charId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `charType` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fame` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `items` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `hp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stats` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"',
  `dead` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tex1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tex2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pet` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fameStats` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'eNoVytkRgCAMRdGH4IIbgmsPdmNVNmZf5n7kzM0kksLjJN2V4b30vcHK1YYam9hCxxqh5zpQI0wwQ4IFMhRYYeNjpw444YIfA3kDIA',
  `createTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deathTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `totalFame` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my first time using MySQL stuff. The reason I am using it because I downloaded a source for a game with server and this is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is isolated to these two lines

```
  `createTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deathTime`  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

To get rid of the error, you need to modify one of those lines to remove the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  MySQL only allows *one* timestamp column to be defined that way.  For example:

```
  `createTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deathTime`  timestamp NOT NULL,
```

Because the `deathTime` column is defined as NOT NULL and doesn't have a default, you'll need to supply a value for `deathTime` whenever you insert a row. You could get the current date and time assigned to that column for an INSERT using a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to, well, define more than "one TIMESTAMP column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in `DEFAULT` or ON `UPDATE` clause". Specifically, `createTime` and `deathTime`.

You Can't Do That.™